# Why reflection is used in this situation

Tags: java, tomcat, reflection

Today, I am looking the source code of tomcat

in the `Bootstrap.init()` method, I found it used reflection to create an instance of `org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina`, and use `invoke()` to set the `ClassLoader`

Like the following code

```java
Class<?> startupClass = catalinaLoader.loadClass("org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina");
Object startupInstance = startupClass.getConstructor().newInstance();
String methodName = "setParentClassLoader";
Method method =
            startupInstance.getClass().getMethod(methodName, paramTypes);
        method.invoke(startupInstance, paramValues);
```

I found that many frameworks use reflections to create an instance, even though the class and method can be determined

Just like the above code, use `String` to determine the target.

Is it still necessary to use reflection?

Comment: This question was useful for me and I'll see if I can edit in certain way to get it opened. For the sake of the question...here is a good explanation that I went to read further https://www.programcreek.com/2013/09/java-reflection-tutorial/

Answer (score 28):

Yes.

For example, Spring uses `<bean>` definitions as such

```
<bean id="someId" class="com.foopack.Foo">
    <property name="someField" value="someValue" />
</bean>
```

When the Spring context processes this `<bean>` element, it will use `Class.forName(String)` with the argument as `com.foopack.Foo` to instantiate that Class (`Class#newInstance()` or get a `Constructor`, depending). It will then again use reflection to get the appropriate setter for the `<property>` element and set its value to the specified `value`.

Junit also uses reflection to get a set of `@Test` annotated methods to invoke. To do this, it needs to get a `Class` instance.

Servlet based web applications also use reflection to instantiate `Servlet`, `Filter`, and the different types of Listeners classes. For example, you would have

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>YourServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.servlets.YourServlet</servlet-class>
<servlet>
```

and the container would take that fully qualified class name, `com.servlets.YourServlet`, and instantiate and register it.

JSON parser/generator libraries also use reflection. For example, with `Gson`, given a class like

```
class Foo {
    private String name = "FOOOO";
}
```

and an instance like this

```
Foo foo = new Foo();
```

you would serialize it like so

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(foo);
```

Gson would then call `getClass()` on the instance `foo`, get a set of the `Field` instances of that `Class`, iterate over the set, and serialize the values of the fields to a JSON format.

Comment: Does this mean that if we use annotations to create Spring beans, instead of XML, reflection won't be needed?

Comment: @onlinenaman Yes and no. `@Autowired` and lifecycle methods like `@PostConstruct are still invoked through reflection. Really, the only difference is what you may be doing in the `@Bean` factory methods, though the `@Bean` methods are also invoked through reflection.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to get `Class` object. `Class.forName` is one of them. Very often it is `obj.getClass().` As for Spring it uses `ClassLoader.loadClass` when loading beans, see `org.springframework.util.ClassUtils` in `spring-core` module.

Answer (score 1):

In this particular example, it looks like reflection is being used as a way ensure that the class (`org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina`) is not loaded and initialized too early.

> Is it still necessary to use reflection?

It is not clear that this (delayed loading) could not be done some other way.

And indeed, this is not *sufficient* to ensure that delayed loading happens.  (If this classes identifier was used somewhere else, that could trigger premature loading.)

---

There are more "modern" approaches to this kind of problem; e.g. Spring's dependency injection.  But the Tomcat codebase predates these innovations by may years.  (And the principle of "if it ain't broken, don't fix it" applies.)